# java 1.8 eclipse luna ClassFormatError Illegal field modifiers

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, junit4

I get this specific message:

> ClassFormatError: Illegal field modifiers in class 0x100A.

It seems like there is a lot of this going around:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435664
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434442
- [java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal field modifiers in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727105/java-lang-classformaterror-illegal-field-modifiers-in-class)
- [ClassFormateError from using switch statements in Java 8's defender methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823563/classformateerror-from-using-switch-statements-in-java-8s-defender-methods)
- [Java 8 ClassFormatException for interface with static methods, but only when using assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771952/java-8-classformatexception-for-interface-with-static-methods-but-only-when-usi)

The program is a Swing app and runs fine from the command line using gradle.

But it is hard to debug things this way and the error moves around.

I need to use Java 1.8. Is there any kind of workaround?

**Edit:** IntelliJ community and netbeans work. but i have poor vision.

**Edit 2:** Now it's failing on almost all of the junit tests. this is most annoying.

**Edit 3:** Trying mars m6. ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l) fixed that problem (see my comment) by making a new project and copying src/ into it. swing app *seems* to work at first glance.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Compiler compliance level` set to `1.8`?

Comment: NetBeans is also visually clear, and not overloaded. This bug will probably be solved very soon.

Comment: it also works in netbeans. just not familiar with the menu tree and shortcuts.

Comment: @RayTayek If you want eclipse shortcuts in netbeans, you can go to `Tools -> Options -> Keymap`, then there will be a dropdown menu called `Profile`, at the top of the dialog. Select eclipse, and most of the eclipse shortcuts will work :) Thought it might be useful in the future

Comment: @ bali182, thanks. that's good to know. i found a workaround though with mars m6: see edit3 in the question.